# PHPで関数で定義した変数を他の関数内で使いたい。

Tags: php

global変数を関数内で使う方法は分かったのですが、関数で定義した変数を他の関数内で使うにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？
下記ではfunc_2()内では$numは未定義なので、Undefined variableになります。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願いします。

```
function func() {
  $num = 10;
}
function func_2() {
  echo $num;
}
func_2();
```

Comment: 回答をスレッドのように使うのはやめましょう。新しい情報は質問を追記して、回答に関する質問はコメントでやり取りしましょう

Comment: そのようにも思ったのですが、コメントでは改行もできず、コードなどを挿入すると、とても見づらいです。これは仕方ありませんか？
それと、このスレッドに回答やコメントが付いた際、自分のメールアドレスに通知させたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょう？設定で見つけられないのですが、助言いただけますでしょうか？

Comment: コードは質問に追記すればよいです。その上でコメントに質問に追記しましたと書けばよいです。通知に関してはヘルプを探してもらい、なければメタで質問をしていただければと思います。私もアプリでの通知しか使っておりませんので詳しくはないですねぇ

Comment: なるほど、了解しました。以前は通知は来ていたのですが、この質問では動作しないのです。もう一度、ヘルプを探してみます。

Comment: モデレータ様にチャットに移行いただきまして、質問は完結しました。そちらはそのままでよいでしょうか？また、こちらの質問自体は解決済みの状態になっているでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$num = 0; // この変数は関数の外なのでグローバルスコープとなります
function func() {
  global $num; // この関数スコープで $num はグローバル変数を参照するという宣言です
  $num = 10;
}
function func_2() {
  global $num; // この関数スコープで $num はグローバル変数を参照するという宣言です
  echo $num . "\n";
}
func_2();
func();
func_2();
```

結果

```
0
10
```

Comment: 回答とコメントで議論が行われたのを、チャットに移動させました。スタック・オーバーフローでは回答には回答のみを書くことになっています。代わりの方法はいくつかありますが今回は複数行のコードを書きたいとのことでしたので、チャットをご案内します。こちらです： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135944/discussion-on-answer-by-itagaki-fumihiko-php

Comment: PHPの出力を直に確認してください。